# Display product types in mutiselect options system configuration in magento 2.2.3

Tags: adminhtml, configuration, magento2.2.3

> app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<field id="display_product_types" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Display Product Types</label>
    <source_model>Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\DisplayProductTypes</source_model>
</field>
```

> app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Model/Config/Source/DisplayProductTypes.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class DisplayProductTypes implements ArrayInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Simple Product')],
            ['value' => '2', 'label' => __('Configurable Product')],
            ['value' => '4', 'label' => __('Virtual Product')],
            ['value' => '6', 'label' => __('Downloadbal Product')]
        ];
    }
}
```

[image: please check screen short]

**Note:** Now product types static how to this option dynamic display in multi select  in system configuration

Answer (score 1):

you need to use below method for that

```
public function __construct(
       ......
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\TypeFactory $typeFactory,
        ..........
    ) {
     $this->_typeFactory = $typeFactory;
}


 public function toOptionArray()
  {
$types = $this->_typeFactory->create()->getTypes();
.....
then do your work

}
```

more info for that

Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product.php file.

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Model/Config/Source/DisplayProductTypes.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class DisplayProductTypes implements ArrayInterface
{
    const SIMPLE_PRODUCT = '1';
    
    const CONFIGURABLE_PRODUCT = '2';
    
    const VIRTUAL_PRODUCT = '4';
    
    const DOWNLOADBAL_PRODUCT = '6';
    
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => self::SIMPLE_PRODUCT, 'label' => __('Simple Product')],
            ['value' => self::CONFIGURABLE_PRODUCT, 'label' => __('Configurable Product')],
            ['value' => self::VIRTUAL_PRODUCT, 'label' => __('Virtual Product')],
            ['value' => self::DOWNLOADBAL_PRODUCT, 'label' => __('Downloadbal Product')]
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create an extra class or anything, just use the below code for showing product types dropdown:

```
<field id="display_product_types" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Display Product Types</label>                        
    <source_model>Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type</source_model>
</field>
```

If you need to change the value of the options or add any condition then only you need to create an additional class.